# Mutate or combine group?

Tags: r

I have a situation where data looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(num1 = c(1234, 4321, NA, NA, NA),
                 num2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 5822, 2661),
                 order1 = c(12,32,NA,NA,NA),
                 order2 = c(NA,NA,NA,44,22)
)
```

num1 and order1 are aligned on row data and num2 and order2 are aligned on row data. This is the way I extracted them using `bind_cols` from their original data frame - they were spread through out the frame in different columns.

Now that I have them together can I

1. Group them so they are together (num1/ord1) next to each other?
2. move num2/ord2 to the end of num1/or1 columns so in the end all data is just in two columns?

I was able to achieve a sloppy version of this creating two separate data frames for each set using bind_cols again.

Comment: I added an answer, but I'm unsure what your expected output should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wanting to put `num1` and `num2` into the same column (and same for `order1` and `order2`, then can use `coalesce`. You can use `select` to reorder columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(num1 = coalesce(num1, num2),
         order1 = coalesce(order1, order2)) %>%
  select(num1, order1)
```

**Output**

```
  num1 order1
1 1234     12
2 4321     32
3   NA     NA
4 5822     44
5 2661     22
```